# how to get values from DB and add those in array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I was googling for and found no results for this. 
most of the people declare the array inside the void. like this

```
private void Something(){
                ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
                list.Add("awdawd");
}
```

but I have to declare the array outside of it because it would be used from different voids. this is my code:

```
 public string[] Names= { "Rick", "Morty", "John" };
```

and for the db:

```
 private void GetNames() {

        string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM Login";

        // using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=TestDB"))
        using (SqlCommand SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(cmdText, connectionstring))
        {
            SqlDataReader myReader;
            connectionstring.Open();
            myReader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();

        }

    }
```

I tried to make it Names.add("Mario");
but it didnt work.

any suggestion?

Comment: Yes. Don't use arrays. use a List<string> instead.

Comment: Do you want to **add** those name to the predefined ones or **replace** the initial array with the values from the database? Arrays don't have an `Add` method. If you want to use `Add`, use a `List<>` instead of an array.

Comment: You should learn the difference between string array and `ArrayList`

Comment: @Sinatr I saw that post too. id didnt help me

Comment: Then you didn't understand it, didn't try it or want something completely different that you ask.

Comment: Ikram gave the answer before, I had to change the list above. and what that post shows is what most of the post I found, they didnt help me. even though I am trying for 35 minutes

Comment: Btw, it's not a [`void`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yah0tteb.aspx) but a [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx) (that doesn't return anything). Your method `GetNames` should either return something(f.e. a `string[]`) or get a different name

Comment: @TimSchmelter can you please explain better?

Comment: @AltjenB.: replace `void` with `string[]`, create a `List<string>` and use `list.Add` in a `while(myReader.Read())`-loop to fill it. Finally `return list.ToArray();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resize the array to add a new element to it, but it's better to use `List<string>` in your case.

```
public List<string> Names= new List<string>(){ "Rick", "Morty", "John" };
```

and then you can add

```
Names.Add("Mario");
```

Comment: thanks, this worked. but how can I find the maximum number of values inside the String Array?
for the old one I used Names.Length

Comment: Names.Count() will give you result

Comment: Check the Names object.  There should be a property that makes sense to have the count.  Probably Count is what you want... just poke around the properties to see what makes sense.

Comment: yes. Names.Count works. thanks